# c# transfer string to another project with no reference

Tags: c#

To clarify, there is a reference in my solution. I currently have 2 projects => UI and Engine. UI references Engine.

I'm looking to transfer a string that is based on user input from the UI project to the Engine project. Specifically the 'GameSession' class. Though I cannot just put it in a string and reference it (Though I'm not sure even that would work) since UI references Engine, not the other way around.

So I've looked to solve this problem this way:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        testvar = boxUser.Text;
        _gameSession.TestMethod(testvar);
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.Show();
    }
```

Here I convert the textbox input to a string, then call the TestMethod in the gameSession class which has a string parametar, putting the input in that method, and open the window where the textbox input should be seen.

```
    private string _test;
    public void TestMethod(string test)
    {
        _test = test;
    }
```

I then define a string _test and in the Method I called earlier then just equal it out.

```
       public GameSession()
    {

        CurrentPlayer = new Player(_test, "Hardcoded", 0, 10, 10, 1000000);
```

Then in the GameSession constructor I create a new instance of a Player with the name as the _test variable (the user input), but when I run it, it just comes out as null when the MainWindow opens. It does take the form of the _test variable after the fact, but I need it to take the form of the variable literally as soon as it can. How would I go about achieveing this? What could I do to improve/rewrite the code for it to work?

Comment: Well, if you create your Player object before the user input happens, only a time machine will help you. Or, in other words: create your Player object only after(!!!) the user input happened (for example, create the Player object in the TestMethod method that received the test string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set a value to `_test` after you have created a player. Re-create a player in `TestMethod` or update name of the player if it's possible.

```
public void TestMethod(string test)
{
    CurrentPlayer = new Player(test, "Hardcoded", 0, 10, 10, 1000000);
}
```

Or

```
public void TestMethod(string test)
{
    CurrentPlayer.Name = test;
}
```

Remember that string is reference type but it is immutable.

```
_test = "some name";
CurrentPlayer = new Player(_test, "Hardcoded", 0, 10, 10, 1000000);
// CurrentPlayer.Name = "some name"

_test = "another name";
// CurrentPlayer.Name will remain "some name"
```

Comment: I've tried both. Just renaming or re-creating the whole Player class in the TestMethod, it doesnt work. Only thing that works ia just instancing the Player in the TestMethod directly, but then my Binding CurrentPlayer.Name doesnt work in the xaml

Comment: UPDATE: just had to add the main.datacontext to be the gamesession in the buttonclick. Solved, thanks